# Remove quotes from list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

How can I remove the single quotes from the following so it can be recognized as a list of one dictionary object as apposed to a list of one string object?  Given that it is a list, I cannot use pd.replace.

```
['{"PLAYER":"Player Name","SALARY":"0000.00","OPP":"CI","POS":"BR","TEAM":"IT","SCHEDULE_ID":"40623","PLAYERID":"12322","GP":"5","TAR":"64","RZTAR":"6","POW TAR":"32.99%","WEEK 2":"11","WEEK 3":"14","WEEK 4":"9","WEEK 5":"19","ARDS":"545","YPT":"8.52","REC":"40","REC RATE":"62.50%"}']
```

Comment: You don't have a list of dictionaries; you have a list of strings. The string appears to be a JSON value, which can be decoded into a dictionary. You need to know the source of the string, though, to be certain how it is to be interpreted.

Comment: I know I didn't have a list of dictionaries. A list of dictionaries was my goal. How to do that was my question which @Ajax1234 answered below. I wanted that list of strings to be viewed as a dictionary. In order to do that, I needed to remove the single quotes from around each would-be dictionary in the list. The "ast" solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s = ['{"PLAYER":"Player Name","SALARY":"0000.00","OPP":"CI","POS":"BR","TEAM":"IT","SCHEDULE_ID":"40623","PLAYERID":"12322","GP":"5","TAR":"64","RZTAR":"6","POW TAR":"32.99%","WEEK 2":"11","WEEK 3":"14","WEEK 4":"9","WEEK 5":"19","ARDS":"545","YPT":"8.52","REC":"40","REC RATE":"62.50%"}']
final_s = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[{'SALARY': '0000.00', 'REC RATE': '62.50%', 'OPP': 'CI', 'YPT': '8.52', 'TAR': '64', 'GP': '5', 'PLAYERID': '12322', 'WEEK 3': '14', 'POS': 'BR', 'ARDS': '545', 'WEEK 2': '11', 'PLAYER': 'Player Name', 'SCHEDULE_ID': '40623', 'POW TAR': '32.99%', 'WEEK 4': '9', 'TEAM': 'IT', 'RZTAR': '6', 'REC': '40', 'WEEK 5': '19'}]
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. I was able to easily complete my next step, which was to turn the list of (now) dictionaries into a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

just use eval() for the purpose

```
s=['{"PLAYER":"PlayerName","SALARY":"0000.00","OPP":"CI","POS":"BR","TEAM":"IT","SCHEDULE_ID":"40623","PLAYERID":"12322","GP":"5","TAR":"64","RZTAR":"6","POW TAR":"32.99%","WEEK 2":"11","WEEK 3":"14","WEEK 4":"9","WEEK 5":"19","ARDS":"545","YPT":"8.52","REC":"40","REC RATE":"62.50%"}']

s = [eval(item) for item in s]
```