# Access a value from a dictionary stored with pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dictionary

I have a data frame that contains a dictionary-like format key-value pairs within a column. However, the dictionary is stored in a string format.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Jose'],
                     'Column2':['{"key": "John_value1", "key2": "John_value2"}','{"key": "Jose_value1", "key2": "Jose_value2"}'],
                    })
```

Since it is stored in a string format I can't access a particular element (eg. "Jose_value2") using the below code

```
df1["Column2"][1]["key2"]
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Can someone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is '' encasing the keys will cause issues accessing the values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Jose'],
                     'Column2':[{"key": "John_value1", "key2": "John_value2"},{"key": "Jose_value1", "key2": "Jose_value2"}],
                    })

print(df1['Column2'][1]['key2'])
```

Outputs:

```
Jose_value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to do it by removing quotes from the list of dictionaries using [ast.literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991650/remove-quotes-from-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)

```
import ast
df1["Column3"] = [ ast.literal_eval(i) for i in df1["Column2"]]
df1["Column3"][1]["key2"]
```

'Jose_value2'

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
import json
key2_value = json.loads(df1["Column2"][1]).get("key2")
```

This converts the string into a dictionary and then gets the value you want.

You can look at json.loads() in detail on the python documentation although I prefer looking at this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/